# John the ripper does not crack password

Tags: password-cracking, sha256

I'd like to attack a self-created sha256 hash with `john --wordlist=`

So far I've done the following:

```
$ echo 'testpassword' | sha256sum > mypassword
```

removed the tail of the output with vim

```
$ cat mypassword
dc460da4ad72c482231e28e688e01f2778a88ce31a08826899d54ef7183998b5
```

penetrate with john

```
$ john --wordlist=list.txt --format=raw-sha256 mypassword
```

result:

```
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 1 password hash (Raw-SHA256 [SHA256 128/128 SSE2 4x])
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:06 DONE (2017-01-06 12:47) 0g/s 2347Kp/s 2347Kc/s 2347KC/s
Session completed
```

show

```
$ john --show mypassword
0 password hashes cracked, 1 left
```

What did I do wrong? Is `raw-sha256` not the right format? The test password is definitely in the wordlist.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your string has an unintended line break at the end. Use `-n` to omit the trailing newline character:

```
echo -n 'testpassword' | sha256sum > mypassword
```

Otherwise you end up with a different hash:

```
$ echo testpassword | sha256sum
e0d7d338cb1259086d775c964fba50b2a84244ba4cd2815e9f6f4a8d9daaa656  -
$ echo -n testpassword | sha256sum
9f735e0df9a1ddc702bf0a1a7b83033f9f7153a00c29de82cedadc9957289b05  -
```

Then just proceed as you did.

Demo:

```
$ echo -n "abc123" | sha256sum | cut -f 1 -d " " > password
$ john --format=raw-sha256 password
$ john --show password
?:abc123

1 password hash cracked, 0 left
```

(I used `cut` to remove the hyphen after the hash.)

Comment: This issue has bitten me in the ass more times than I wish to admit!

Comment: So basically you're saying we can create impenetrable passwords by adding a line break at the end? ;)

Comment: For increased security any control character should work. But you need U.I. support to enter them.

Comment: @Jezzamon Even better - put a NULL byte at the end, john can't handle them

Comment: @Jasen I was bitten by this when moving from Win7 to Win10, they removed the ability to type a literal delete char into the password box at login.